# Is it possible to change the rewrite rules in asp.net mvc web.config using code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, mod-rewrite

I want to be able to add/update/delete rewrite rules from the web.config.

Is this possible and are there any gotchas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Global.asax to do routing. You can also write custom class so the rules can be defined in a database or xml file.